# python PuLP to choose the optimal combination of items from list

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I currently need to optimize the 'rating' with the constraint of 'distance'. In this case, i want to let PuLP choose the optimal index of the items. Distance is the distance from the start, not from one point to another.

```
distance = [12, 326, 347, 359, 553, 590, 687, 1007, 1008, 1321, 1360, 1411]
rating = [4.3, 4.8, 2.7, 2.6, 3.6, 0.8, 4.4, 2.8, 2.6, 2.1, 2.8, 3.3]
total_score = LpProblem("hotel", LpMaximize)
A = LpVariable('A', lowBound=0 , cat=LpInteger)
B = LpVariable('B', lowBound=0 , cat=LpInteger)
C = LpVariable('C', lowBound=0 , cat=LpInteger)
D = LpVariable('D', lowBound=0 , cat=LpInteger)
E = LpVariable('E', lowBound=0 , cat=LpInteger)

total_score += rating[A] + rating[B] + rating[C] + rating[D] + rating[E]  
total_score += 6*60 + distance[E] >= b
totel_score += distance[B] - distance[A] <= 360
totel_score += distance[C] - distance[B] <= 360
totel_score += distance[D] - distance[C] <= 360
totel_score += distance[E] - distance[D] <= 360
```

the rating should be the maximum, the difference of the distances should not exeed 360, and distance needs to reach a certain value. Additionally, only five items can be chosen

I know that the first two constraints could be written as

```
n = len(distance)
N = range(n)
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', N, cat="Binary")

# OBJECTIVE
prob += lpSum([rating[i]*x[i] for i in N])
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in N]) <= max_to_pick        # Limit number to include
prob += lpSum([x[i]*distance[i] for i in N]) >= max_dist  # Limit max. cost
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to implement the conditions where the difference of the distance between two chosen points is not allowed to go above 360